# Difference between "search of" and "search for"

Tags: usage, verbs, nouns

I was writing a classified for a company, but I got confused between two different usage of 'search'.

Read the following sentences:

> If you're in ***search of*** a quality marketing company, then your search ends here!
>
> If you're in ***search for*** a quality marketing company, then your search ends here!

Now, I want to know what native speakers say about the usage in above written sentences. Are they both okay? Why?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The correct phrase is "in search of".

Answer (score 16):

The first sentence, using "in search of", is the correct one.

1. "in search of" is an idiomatic phrase, equivalent to "searching for". These mean the same thing:

   > I am **in search of** a good pair of shoes.
   >
   > I am **searching for** a good pair of shoes.
2. "in search for" is not strictly correct English; there should be an article ("a" or "the") before "search". Leaving articles out is common when trying to be brief, like in news headlines, as seen in Maulik V's answer:

   > FBI involved **in search for** brothers missing in Matamoros.
   >
   > The FBI is involved **in the** [or **a**] **search for** two brothers who are missing in Matamoros.

These other two cases are not directly relevant to your specific question, but may help to clarify general uses of "search of/for", when *not* preceded by "in".

3. "search for X" means that X is the thing you're trying to find.
4. "search of X" means that X is the location where you're searching.

> My sunglasses are missing. A **search of** my car did not find them. The **search for** my sunglasses is still going.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the word 'search' is typically a *noun*! But then, idiomatically, it can be used as a 'verb'.

The [American Heritage Idioms Dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/in+search+of) defines it:

> Looking for, seeking, as in They went to California ***in search of gold,*** or I went to the library in quest of a quiet place to read.

On the other hand, *in search for* is possible but it's probably used in headlines or in the context where the 'search' has begun for something missing. This **may** include some illegal things/people, conspiracy etc.

For instance,

> FBI Involved ***in Search for*** Brothers **Missing** in Matamoros.

Another one...

> Help sought ***in search for*** a man **suspected** in...

So, to answer, better go with 'in search of'... hoping that your company does all good activities! :P

Comment: Both of the "in search for" examples are _Headline-ese_ - they sound fine in that context, but would make a reader stumble if they were used in otherwise regular prose.