# Difference between "in search of" and "in search for"

Tags: prepositions, idioms

> I am in search of cheap labour.
>
> I am in search for cheap labour.

how do you know which preposition to use?

is it collocation?

Comment: "How do you know which preposition to use?"  Mostly, you just have to learn them.  You search *for* something, but you're in search *of* something; you can think *about* something or *on* something; you are *on* good terms with someone but you are *in* a bad mood, etc.

Comment: so,it is a collocation,am i right?

Comment: I would not exactly call it a collocation, because a collocation means "words usually used together".  These prepositions aren't just usually used with these particular words, they go together almost inextricably.

Comment: The example sentence is excerpted from a longer quote at http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/74414

Comment: When words are often used together (eg 'in search of') so that an alternative ('in search by/on/...) is unacceptable (arguably ungrammatical), the string is called a colligation.

Answer (score 3):

See the following answer:

### [Difference between “search of” and “search for”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/49204/24690)

> "in search of" is an idiomatic phrase, equivalent to "searching for". These mean the same thing:
>
> > I am **in search of** a good pair of shoes.
> >
> > I am **searching for** a good pair of shoes.

### Therefore

> I am **in search of** cheap labour.
>
> I am **searching for** cheap labour.

Answer (score 2):

Better would be **I am searching for cheap labour** as the second choice. From my experience, one **searches for** something, or is **in search of** something else.